How can I reset Timeouts/animations? (Ionic/Angular)
I want to display some messages in a sort off in app notification.
It is supposed to behave like this:

click on a button
notification slides down + display text
notification slides back up
If there are more than one simultaneous message displays the next message after 2 seconds and so on.

What I want is, when I click on the button and there is the notification animation still running to completely stop that animation and imidiately display the new one like this:

click on a button
notification slides down + display text
click again
timer/messages reset
display the new messages + run the timer again
notification slides back up

I have done this previously on another project but the same method is not working in this one as I get this errors:

Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS' [ng] 11   endAnimationTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
[ng] 10   startAnimationTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;

Note: this message component is called on another component
TS:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidatorsService } from '../../../services/validators.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.scss'],
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  startAnimationTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
  endAnimationTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;

  constructor(public validatorsService: ValidatorsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let card = document.querySelector('.message-card') as HTMLDivElement;
    let timeBar = document.querySelector('.time-bar') as HTMLDivElement;
    this.showMessage(card, timeBar);
  }

  messageAnimation(card: HTMLDivElement, timeBar: HTMLDivElement) {
    if (this.validatorsService.messageIndex <= this.validatorsService.messages.length - 1) {
      timeBar.classList.remove('slideToLeft')
    }

    clearTimeout(this.startAnimationTimeout);
    this.startAnimationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeBar.classList.add('slideToLeft');

      this.endAnimationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.validatorsService.messageIndex >= this.validatorsService.messages.length - 1) {
          card.classList.replace('slideDown', 'slideUp');

          setTimeout(() => {
            card.classList.replace('slideUp', 'hide');
            timeBar.classList.remove('slideToLeft')
          }, 750);
        }
      }, 2000);
    }, 500);
  }

  showMessage(card: HTMLDivElement, timeBar: HTMLDivElement) {
    if (this.validatorsService.messages.length === 1) {
      clearTimeout(this.startAnimationTimeout);
      clearTimeout(this.endAnimationTimeout);
      this.messageAnimation(card, timeBar);
      return;
    }

    if (this.validatorsService.messageIndex >= this.validatorsService.messages.length) {
      clearTimeout(this.startAnimationTimeout);
      return;
    }

    this.messageAnimation(card, timeBar);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.validatorsService.messageIndex++;
      this.messageAnimation(card, timeBar);
      this.showMessage(card, timeBar);
    }, 2600);

    return;
  };
}

HTML:
<div #card class="message-card slideDown">
  <p class="message"
    [ngClass]="{'validMessage': validatorsService.messageType === 'success', 'warningMessage': validatorsService.messageType === 'warning'}">
    <span *ngIf="validatorsService.messageType === 'error'">Error
      {{validatorsService.messageIndex + 1}} of {{validatorsService.messages.length}}:</span>
    {{validatorsService.messages[validatorsService.messageIndex]}}</p>

  <div #timeBar class="time-bar"
    [ngClass]="{'valid': validatorsService.messageType === 'success', 'warning': validatorsService.messageType === 'warning'}">
  </div>
</div>

here is the validators service as requested + the functions used on the button click:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidatorsService {
  messages: string[] = [];
  messageIndex: number = 0;
  messageType: string = 'error';
  showMessage: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  // Form validations
  noSpaceAllowed(control: AbstractControl) {
    let parentControl: any = control.parent;
    let controlName;

    if (parentControl) {
      controlName = Object.keys(parentControl.controls).find(key => parentControl.controls[key] === control);
    }

    if (control.value !== null && control.value.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} can't contain spaces.` };
    }

    return null;
  }

  noEmptyAllowed(control: AbstractControl) {
    let parentControl: any = control.parent;
    let controlName;

    if (parentControl) {
      controlName = Object.keys(parentControl.controls).find(key => parentControl.controls[key] === control);
    }

    if (control.value !== null && control.value === '') {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} can't be empty.` };
    }

    return null;
  }

  lengthRangeAllowed(control: AbstractControl) {
    let parentControl: any = control.parent;
    let controlName;

    if (parentControl) {
      controlName = Object.keys(parentControl.controls).find(key => parentControl.controls[key] === control);
    }

    if (controlName === 'email' && control.value !== null && control.value.length > 254) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} must have less then 254 characters.` };
    }

    if (controlName === 'username' && control.value !== null && control.value.length > 20) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} must have less then 20 characters.` };
    }

    if (controlName === 'password' && control.value !== null && control.value.length < 6) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} must contain a minimum of 6 characters.` };
    }

    if (controlName === 'password' && control.value !== null && control.value.length > 24) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} must have less then 24 characters.` };
    }

    return null;
  }

  noSpaceOnlyAllowed(control: AbstractControl) {
    let parentControl: any = control.parent;
    let controlName;

    if (parentControl) {
      controlName = Object.keys(parentControl.controls).find(key => parentControl.controls[key] === control);
    }

    if (control.value !== null && control.value !== '' && /^\s*$/.test(control.value)) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} can't contain just spaces.` };
    }

    return null;
  }

  noConsecutiveSpacesAllowed(control: AbstractControl) {
    let parentControl: any = control.parent;
    let controlName;

    if (parentControl) {
      controlName = Object.keys(parentControl.controls).find(key => parentControl.controls[key] === control);
    }

    if (control.value !== null && control.value !== '' && /\s{2,}/.test(control.value)) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} can't contain consecutive spaces.` };
    }

    return null;
  }

  noStartNorEndSpacesAllowed(control: AbstractControl) {
    let parentControl: any = control.parent;
    let controlName;

    if (parentControl) {
      controlName = Object.keys(parentControl.controls).find(key => parentControl.controls[key] === control);
    }

    if (control.value !== null && control.value !== '' && control.value.startsWith(" ")) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} can't start with a space.` };
    }

    if (control.value !== null && control.value !== '' && control.value.endsWith(" ")) {
      return { error: `Your ${controlName} can't end with a space.` };
    }

    return null;
  }

  acceptToSValidation(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.value !== null && control.value === false) { return { error: 'You Must Agree to the Terms & Conditions.' }; }

    return null;
  }
}

formValidation() {
    this.validatorsService.messages = [];
    this.validatorsService.messageIndex = 0;

    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
      let control: any = this.form.controls[key];

      if (control.errors) {
        Object.keys(control.errors).forEach(error => {
          this.validatorsService.messages.push(control.errors[error]);
        });
      };
    });

    this.validatorsService.showMessage = true;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.validatorsService.showMessage = false

    Object.values(this.form.controls).forEach(control => {
      control.markAsTouched();
    });

    if (this.form.valid === false) {
      this.validatorsService.messageType = 'error';
      this.formValidation();
      return;
    }

    this.validatorsService.messageType = 'success';

    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

html to show the message on another component:
<app-message *ngIf="this.validatorsService.showMessage"></app-message>


Could you please share your ValidatorsService file

@Pykara_Developer added more files as per your request

Instead of NodeJS.Timeout, you should use number for the type of the timeout variable.
startAnimationTimeout: number | undefined;
endAnimationTimeout: number | undefined;


Doesn't really work I still have the same problem where the timeouts nor the animation resets
